# scala code snippet

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. Could anyone please explain the following piece of code to me?

```
 val l: Either[String, Int] = Left("flower")
 val r: Either[String, Int] = Right(12)
 l.left.map(_.size): Either[Int, Int] // Left(6)
 r.left.map(_.size): Either[Int, Int] // Right(12)
```

I have a few questions regarding line 3 and line 4:

1. What does _.size stand for in the context?
2. What does r.left returns?
3. What does r.left.map returns?
4. What does r.left.map(_.size): Either[Int, Int] mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line defines a variable `l` of type `Either[String, Int]`. The `Either` (abstract) class is used to denote when something can hold one of two possible values. The `Left` and `Right` classes subclass `Either`, hence the valid assignment. A convention is to use `Left` to denote some sort of failure (e.g. a `String` describing what went wrong), and `Right` to denote some sort of successful computation/value. With this info, the second line is fairly self explanatory as well.

The 3rd and 4th line use projections on the `l` and `r` variables and perform a `map`. The `left` and `right` methods return projections.. if you project `left` on a `Left` variable, you can then `map` over the inside value. If you project `right` on a `Left` variable, you get the `Right` un-altered even after the `map`. Same if you do `right` on a `Left`, etc.

So the 3rd line, since `l` is a `Left` and you `left` project it, you apply the `map` over the `Left("flower")` value giving you `Left(6)` since "flower" has length 6.

On the 4th line, `r` is `Right` so it does nothing.

For your questions:

1. `_.size` is the function passed to the `map` method.. the `map` method "unpacks" the value inside the `Left` (it does nothing to the `Right` on line 4 since it's a left projection) and calls `.size` on it.
2. `r.left` returns a left projection on the `Right(12)` value. Mapping over this does nothing, as seen in line 4 of your code.
3. The same old `Right(12)` value.
4. Since it is `Right(12)` and of type `Right[_, Int]`, it subclasses `Either[Int, Int]`, so it's valid. It is just there to show the type I believe.

If you go to the REPL and type something like `val foo = Right(1234)`, you get a type `Right[Nothing, Int]` - this "works" because the `Nothing` type subclasses all types.

On a related note, once you start feeling comfortable with that and/or Scala, I recommend checkout Scalaz (a library for Scala that provides functional programming things like type classes, monads, and all that good stuff) and the `Validation` class which is pretty similar to `Either`.